# React-Apollo catch when server is down

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo, apollo-client

In my React ApolloGraphQL app with a node server, I'm trying to have it catch errors when my node server is down. All works great and normal when the node server us up... graphQL errors are caught and displayed.  But when I stop the node server, I get a runtime error that I can't avoid. When the node server is down, the server responds with a `503 Service Unavailable` response and an html page that isn't JSON.

The apollo client is set up like this:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  assumeImmutableResults: true,
  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: "include"
  },
  fetch: fetch,
  onError: ({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors)
      graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
        console.log(`[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,),);
    if (networkError) {console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);}
    response = {errors:null};
  },
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    freezeResults: true,
    dataIdFromObject: obj => {
      let dataId = null;
      switch (obj.__typename) {
        default:
          dataId = defaultDataIdFromObject(obj);
      }
      return dataId;
    },
    cacheRedirects: {
      Query: {
        productVariant: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) => {
          const cacheKey = getCacheKey({ __typename: "ProductVariant", ...args });
          return cacheKey;
        }
      }
    },
  }),
});
```

The above `onError` block response with this message:

```
Error: Network error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I have the mutation set up this way:

```
const [mutateVariant, {data, error, loading}] = useMutation(UPDATE_PRODUCT_META);
```

And I call it like so:

```
mutateVariant({ variables: {inputM: {...buildMetaInput(editedData)} }, 
    errorPolicy: 'ignore', onError: (error) => Logger("Error:", error)});
```

You can see I've tried it with different `errorPolicy` settings and adding an `onError` callback.

But I keep getting unhandled runtime errors and don't seem to be able to catch and handle them:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Network error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
Call Stack
ApolloError           webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.esm.js (76:28)
error                 webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.esm.js (1041:48)
notifySubscription    webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (140:18)
onNotify              webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (179:21)
error                 webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (240:15)
error/<               webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.esm.js (880:76)
error                 webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.esm.js (880:27)
notifySubscription    webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (140:18)
onNotify              webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (179:21)
error                 webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (240:15)
error                 webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-link-error/lib/bundle.esm.js (53:34)
notifySubscription    webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (140:18)
onNotify              webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (179:21)
error                 webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (240:15)
createHttpLink/</</<  webpack-internal:///./node_modules/apollo-link-http/lib/bundle.esm.js (92:26)
```

the returned `error` data from the useMutation hook:

```
graphQLErrors: Array []
message: "Network error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
​networkError: {…}
​  ​bodyText: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>503 Service 
  Unavailable</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>\n<p>The server is temporarily unable 
  to service your\nrequest due to maintenance downtime or capacity\nproblems. Please try again later.  
  </p>\n<p>Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable\nerror was encountered while trying to use an 
  ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>\n</body></html>\n"
  name: "ServerParseError"
​​  response: Object {  }
​​  statusCode: 503
```

How do I catch this error?

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes sense (at all), but if you don't find a better solution, you can wrap the fetch function (e.g. `const newFetch = (url, options) => {/* ... */}`) you pass into new ApolloClient. In your wrapper you can check for your error and return a simulated mock response in that case ‍♀️. I would look for less clever solutions than this though lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutateVariant function returns a promise. Try adding a .catch() after it is called.

```
mutateVariant().catch(() => {...});
```